# Autoit SendMessage and Imagesearch in minimized window

Tags: autoit

I have this code to send mouse actions to an inactive window, but I don't know why it's not working, and it doesn't give any error. Include part is with <> which I removed them. In this example I want to draw a line in paint.
I also need a dll or au3 file for imagesearch in minimized windows. I searched whole net, but couldn't find one that works.
I appreciate your help.

```
include SendMessage.au3    
Include WinAPI.au3    
Global $wHandle = "Untitled - Paint"    
ControlClickDrag($wHandle,"left",300,300,100,80)    
Func ControlClickDrag($wHandle, $Button="left", $X1="", $Y1="", $X2="", $Y2="")
    Local $MK_LBUTTON = 0x0001    
Local $WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201    
Local $WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202    
Local $MK_RBUTTON = 0x0002    
Local $WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204    
Local $WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205    
Local $WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200    
Local $i = 0    
Select    
Case $Button = "left"    
$Button = $MK_LBUTTON    
$ButtonDown = $WM_LBUTTONDOWN    
$ButtonUp = $WM_LBUTTONUP    
Case $Button = "right"    
$Button = $MK_RBUTTON    
$ButtonDown = $WM_RBUTTONDOWN    
$ButtonUp = $WM_RBUTTONUP    
EndSelect    
DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "SendMessage", "hwnd", $wHandle, "int", $ButtonDown, "int", $Button, "long", _MakeLong($X1, $Y1))    
DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "SendMessage", "hwnd", $wHandle, "int", $ButtonUp, "int", $Button, "long", _MakeLong($X2, $Y2))    
EndFunc    
Func _MakeLong($LoWord,$HiWord)    
Return BitOR($HiWord * 0x10000, BitAND($LoWord, 0xFFFF))    
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global $wHandle = "Untitled - Paint"

This isn't a handle. It's just a string.

Replace it with this:

```
Global $wHandle =   ControlGetHandle("Untitled - Paint", "",[CLASS:Afx:00007FF7B1BD0000:8; INSTANCE:1]")
```

You can use Au3Info.exe to get the necessary information to do this for other programs.

Comment: I have this file, and this command: 
http://s9.picofile.com/file/8273721684/PostMessage.zip.html

_PostMessage_Send($wHandle, $VK_F1,  10)
Why it's not working?

Comment: Richard, can you please tell me about ImageSearch too?
Thanks

Comment: ImageSearch:https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148005-imagesearch-usage-explanation/
I'm not sure about the other one. The same method works fine if notepad is the target

Comment: I have read all those topics in that website, and I tried all of them. But I don't know why they don't work (either give errors or don't find anything). Can you please give me a simple example with functions used, in paint or notepad? to find an image when the window is minimized? I appreciate it.

Comment: Having taken another look at it, I don't believe you can use imagesearch in a minimised windows. What effect are you trying to achieve? There may be other ways of doing the same thing

Comment: I wanna make a script for MEmu android emulator. The drag works perfect on Paint, but not on MEmu while in games, and I don't know why.

I know there is these two for imagesearch in minimized window, but I don't know how to get it to work:

DllCall($pImageLib, "str", "ImageSearchEx", "int", $x1, "int", $y1, "int", $right, "int", $bottom, "str", $findImage, "ptr", $HBMP)

DllCall($pImageLib, "str", "ImageSearchExt", "int", $x1, "int", $y1, "int", $right, "int", $bottom, "int", $Tolerance, "ptr", $findImage, "ptr", $HBMP)

Comment: I think this is going to be very difficult (or impossible), and the AutoIt community frowns upon game automation, so you are going to struggle to find the information you need.